# Why doesn't the WebSphere 7 console "_Save_ directly to master configuration" appear when I make a change?

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, websphere

I'm using WebSphere 7 (running my web app from within IBM RAD 7).

I'm trying to enable application security for my web app.

In the console, when I select Security > Global Security > Administrative Security, check "Enable administrative security" and click "Apply" ... there appears a box at the top of the console that says (among other things) "*Save* directly to the master configuration".  I click "Save" and the changes are saved.

However, when I select Applications > Application Types > WebSphere enterprise applications > "MyAppEAR" > Security role to user/group mapping, and map my user group to my user, the "*Save* directly..." link never appears.

I can't figure out how to save my user-to-group mappings.  While they appear in the on screen table of mappings, as soon as I click away and come back, they are gone.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out my problem is exactly this same at this guy's problem:

[Security role to user/group mapping in WebSphere 7 with file-based user registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387261/security-role-to-user-group-mapping-in-websphere-7-with-file-based-user-registry)

I used his solution to work around the missing "OK"/"Save" buttons.

Answer (score 3):

Within RAD, edit your server definition (double click on WebSphere Application Server in the Servers view).  Under the section "Publishing settings for WebSphere Application Server", check "Run server with Resources on Server" (versus within the workspace).

Restart everything and retry your role mapping.

Also note that user/group mapping via the WebSphere console is a multi-step process.  You must click OK on the "Security role to user/group mapping" after returning from the panel on which you actually map roles.  (That is, you must click OK twice to get the role mappings to stick.)

Comment: I did everything you said, but I still have the same problem.  The _save_ (or _ok_) never appears on the "Security role to user/group mapping" page after mapping users to groups.  <sigh>

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any answer. Can i suggest that you try another browser (you might think i am crazy but when i see things not working as expected i would try something like this).

If you make changes and the Server has recognized that there are changes it should give you the option to save.

In this case, it doesn't provide this information implies the server is not receiving the changes hence the suggestion to try and use another browser.

I have seen crazy stuff when i use Chrome (which is my preferred browser) and i switch to FF when the web application behaviour is bizzare.

HTH

Comment: thanks, at least your answer leads me to think that *I* am not the problem here :)

Comment: Robert, post in your observations after using another browser. Which browser are you using @ the moment when you observed this behaviour?

Comment: I'm using Firefox.  I tested it on Firefox and IE.  Sadly same thing on both browsers, and (believe it or not) I'm not allowed to install any other browsers on the machine.  But since I do see the 'save' when I do the first thing I described, I don't think it's a browser issue, tho.